# How to compile openCV to be guaranteed single threaded?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I'm using openCV in a multithreaded software and I'm starting as many threads as CPUs are available. Further I'm using some openCV functions and there my problem starts. It seems to me that openCV internally starts own threads.

```
$ ps huH p 30266 | wc -l
1650
```

1650 Threads??? What are the cmake flags to stop openCVs multithreading support?

Comment: I think you can do it at runtime with `omp_set_num_threads(1);` - though I have never tried.

Comment: Will this affect my program and std::thread?

Comment: I've tried to compile with
`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DWITH_TBB=OFF -DWITH_OPENMP=OFF -DWITH_CSTRIPES=OFF -DWITH_PTHREADS_PF=OFF -DENABLE_SSE=ON -DENABLE_SSE2=ON -DENABLE_SSE3=ON -DENABLE_SSSE3=ON -DENABLE_SSE41=ON -DENABLE_SSE42=ON -DENABLE_POPCNT=ON -DENABLE_AVX=ON -DENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON ..`
but again the number of threads is extreme high
`$ ps huH p 47241 | wc -l` shows `1202`

Comment: `omp_set_num_threads(1);` don't help. `ps huH p 47241 | wc -l` shows `1449`

Comment: `cv::setNumThreads()` called at runtime should work. And not only for omp.

Comment: I gave up with opencv, not because of threading only but the speed compared to ffmpeg is very poor.

Answer (score 2):

As [mainactual](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5878054/mainactual) mentioned, you can set the number of threads at runtime using `cv::setNumThreads(int nthreads)`.
Refer [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gae78625c3c2aa9e0b83ed31b73c6549c0) for more information.